# Newbie - First Apex Class question re: No viable alternative character

Tags: apex, string, compile-error

I'm doing one of the Trails, converting my .NET and Java knowledge over. I'm stumped on a really simple task.

Objective: Return a list of accounts where the BillingState is the same as the state abbreviation passed in.

Here's my code. I keep being told that I have a 'no viable alternative at character "''"  ... I have no idea what that means.

```
public with sharing class AccountUtils {

    public static List<Account> accountsByState (string stateAbbreviation)
    {
        Set<string> states = new Set<string>  {stateAbbreviation};
        List<Account> accounts = [Select Id, Name from Account where account.BillingState in :states];

        return accounts;
    }
}
```

Also - I tried the BillingState without the account[dot], tried having BillingState = stateAbbreviation. I'm not sure what I'm doing right, and what wrong.

**Problem Script**

```
AccountUtils.accountsByState("AL")
```

**Error Message**

> Line 1, Column 29. No viable alternative at character "''"

Comment: You have not shared the problematic code with us.

Comment: The line that I run in the debugger is: AccountUtils.accountsByState("AL")  And the Execute Anonymous Error I get is "Line 1, Column 29. No viable alternative at character "''"

Comment: Might I suggest working through: [Mapping .NET Concepts to Force.com](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/apex_basics_dotnet/mapping_concepts) (If that isn't the one you are already working on)

Comment: That was the one I was working on, Daniel. It missed a few concepts. I went through the material a dozen times before asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you don't try to declare a string wrapped in double quotes. Only single quotes are allowed in `Apex`.

**Fails**

```
String s = "Some Value";
```

**Works**

```
String s = 'Some Value';
```

It's worth noting from **[Apex Code: The Basics](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code:_The_Basics)**:

> - Strings have the following features:
>
>   - They must be surrounded by single quotes.
>   - The same parsing rules apply as SOQL strings.
>   - String field values can never be empty (only null).
>   - String field values are always trimmed (the same semantics as Oracle and the AppExchange API). However, script-level String values can be empty or have leading or trailing spaces.
>   - The same escape sequences are currently used as for SOQL strings.

Comment: After reading this and thinking about it, I played around with the debugger call. I changed it from "AL" to 'AL', and added a ;   However, now I'm told that the method doesn't exist.   Method does not exist or incorrect signature: AccountUtils.accountsByState(String)

Comment: Did the `AccountUtils` class actually compile? Are you sure your save operation succeeded? Normally you would see that if you forgot to mark the method as `static`, but that is not the case in what you posted.

Comment: AHHHH I didn't realize that saving was effectively compiling (paradigm difference). Thank you. I saved it, then it worked fine.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. :)

Comment: Glad it's working now. Here's an error unrelated tip:
There;s no need to convert the passed parameter to a set and use "in" in the query. [Select Id, Name from Account where account.BillingState = :stateAbbreviation] will work fine and you can get rid of the Set variable.